# how to handle redux props in class methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

in my react App i'm using `redux` with `redux-thunk`.right now i'm getting `props` in my component but i'm unable to access **latest** `props` in my component `methods`
so i used `componentWillReceiveProps` to get **latest** props using `nextprops` then i'm saving `nextprops` into my `states` but the problem here is `setState` is **asynchronous** 
so when i'm fetching **particular state** in class methods,getting **prev state** value instead of `nextprops` value which is saved in state. but when i'm console those `state` in **class methods** using `setInterval` getting **latest state** value because `setState` value now saved.**below is my code**

**Action** creator

```
export function pickup(latlng) {

    return function(dispatch) {
        dispatch({ type: PICKUP_STATE,payload:latlng });
    };

}
```

**Reducer**

```
import {
    PICKUP_STATE,
    PICKUP_ADD,
    DROPOFF_STATE
} from '../actions/types';

    export default  (state={},action) => {
        const INITIAL_STATE = {
            pickup: '',
            pickupAdd:''
        };
        switch(action.type) {
            case PICKUP_STATE:
                console.log(action.payload)
                return {...state,pickup:action.payload};
            case PICKUP_ADD:
                return{...state,pickupAdd:action.payload};
            case DROPOFF_STATE:
                return {...state,dropoff:action.payload}
            default:
                return state;
        }
        //return state;
    }
```

**component**

```
import {
    connect
} from "react-redux";
import * as actions from "../actions"
class Map extends React.Component {
      componentWillReceiveProps(nextprops) {
             if (nextprops.pickupProps !== undefined) {
                 this.setState({
                     pick: nextprops.pickupProps
                 }, () => {
                     console.log(this.state.pick);

                 });
             }
       }
   isPickEmpty(emptyPickState) {
        this.props.pickup(emptyPickState);
    // setTimeout(() =>{ console.log('sdkjlfjlksd',this.state.pick) 
                        },3000);
        console.log(this.state.pick);
   }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    // console.log(state.BookingData.pickup);
    return {
        pickupProps:state.BookingData.pickup,
        pickupAddProps: state.BookingData.pickupAdd
        }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,actions)(Map);
```

**App Root** file

```
import React        from "react";
import ReactDOM     from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import "normalize.css/normalize.css"
import  "./styles/styles.scss";
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

import AppRouter from './routers/AppRouter';
import reducers from './reducers';
import {AUTH_USER} from "./actions/types";


const middleware = [
    reduxThunk,
];

const store = createStore(reducers, composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
// other store enhancers if any
));



const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
if(token){
    store.dispatch({type:AUTH_USER});
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <AppRouter />
    </Provider>
    , document.getElementById('app'));
```

1- how can i access **latest** `props` in my **class methods**
             OR
2- how can i access `nextprops` `setState` value in my **class methods**
  OR
3- **any best way** to solve this situation

**please any one help me out from this situation, i'm stuck in from 3 days**

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you still need to add a maps to dispatch to get the updated states from the store. The action creator still needs to be called and then mount it to your class method using componenetsDidMount

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchPickUp();
  }

const mapDispatch = dispatch => {
  return {
    fetchPickUp: () => dispatch(pickUp()),
  };
```

Comment: i'm doing same thing in **Action creator**,isn't it...? then i'm connecting as `actions` in connect.which holds all dispacthes

Comment: I think the action creator still needs to be invoked in your component else you will receive the initial states.

Comment: can u elaborate.....,how can i connect `actions`(my actions file) and `mapDispatch` function

Comment: It is based on which file you want to access the new state. in your component file you can add mapDispatch function below mapState and add componenetWillMount in lieu of componentWillReceiveProps to get the  new state.

Comment: prblm is not about fetching and dispatching, how can i access redux props in my class functions,like here `pickup`.because already i'm able to dispatch and fetch the props but not in funcitons

Comment: if you want to access pickupProps (as you have defined in your mapState), in you component you can add constructor and super with props as a parameter and then use this.props

class Map extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props)
    }

componentWillMount() {
     const {pickupProps} = this.props
}

Comment: i know that method but i want <br>
 how can i access latest props in my class methods
OR
2- how can i access nextprops setState value in my class methods
OR
3- any best way to solve this situation